# Error while building sample application viewer located under skia/platform_tools/android directory

Tags: android, skia

**Steps to reproduce the problem?**

1. bin/gn gen out/arm64 --args='ndk="/home/anurag/Android/android-ndk-r19" ndk_api=27 target_os="android" target_cpu="arm64" is_component_build=true is_debug=false'
2. ninja -C out/arm64 
   *Output of this step is [image]*
3. platform_tools/android/bin/android_build_app -C out/arm64 viewer

**Expected output?**

Upon completion of the script the APK can be found at out_dir/viewer.apk as per documentation mentioned on https://skia.org/user/sample/viewer

**Actual Output**

Instead, an error is printed on the console as:

```
$ platform_tools/android/bin/android_build_app -C out/arm64 viewer

> Configure project :viewer 
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (22.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :viewer:arm64Debug_BuildSkiaLib FAILED
ninja: Entering directory `/disk2/workspace/android-studio-office/skia/out/arm64'
ninja: error: unknown target 'libviewer'


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':viewer:arm64Debug_BuildSkiaLib'.
> Process 'command '/disk2/workspace/android-studio-office/depot_tools/ninja'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
16 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 15 up-to-date
Command '['./apps/gradlew', ':viewer:assemblearm64debug', '-papps/viewer', '-Parm64.out.dir=/disk2/workspace/android-studio-office/skia/out/arm64', '--daemon']' returned non-zero exit status 1
gradle build failed
```

I am using product version 74 as per https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+/master/include/core/SkMilestone.h

Operating system version: Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: hi Anurag, i'm getting the same error. did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Siva  it's been a long time. I am sorry, cannot recall as of now.